# htaccess 301 rewrite regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to use htaccess to 301 redirect this:

```
http://olddomain.com/oldsubdir/pagename.aspx
```

to this:

```
https://www.newdomain.com/newsubdir/PAGENAME
```

changes:

- http -> https
- add 'www.'
- olddomain, newdomain, oldsubdir, and newsubdir are constants
- pagename is variable and will contain letters [a-zA-Z] and may or may not contain a '.' (if there is a '.' then it will have alpha letters on both sides of it; such as abc.def.aspx where 'abc.def' is pagename, and '.aspx' is the suffix we're trying to strip off)
- remove '.aspx'
- if possible, UPPERCASE pagename in the process (it's a stock symbol)

I am assuming I will put the resulting redirect line in my .htaccess file in the root of olddomain.com. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$
RewriteRule ^oldsubdir/([a-zA-Z\.]+).aspx$ https://www.newdomain.com/newsubdir/$1 [R=301]
```

I don't think transform pagename to PAGENAME is possible.

Comment: I'm a new user and they won't let me +1 (not enough reputation). Once I'm able, I will. Thanks!